# If findbyidanddelete() finds no users the catch block should be executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z03F2.png)

So i am reading this nodejs PDF guide and i found this.

Why is there a **if(!user)** conditions 
If no user is found the execution would jump to catch block so i really cant understand when would this statement execute .

It would be really helpful if someone can explain this to me .

Comment: please add your code to the post.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see if it went to catch block or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without the implementation of `User.findByIdAndDelete`.

But maybe if there is no *id* parameter on the request (ie `req.params.id` is `undefined`), the code will throw an error, falling on the catch statement (anyway could be useful for the user to have at least the e.message or the e.name if present)...

But this is pure speculation :)

---

## EDIT

I found the source code of mongoose on [github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose)!

the function `Model.findByIdAndDelete` can throw a `TypeError` if `arguments.length === 1 && typeof id === 'function'`

I found it [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2bea45372a2bb8c19c6f8d27f004e43df9906ea6/lib/model.js#L2767)

Comment: `findByIdAndDeltete` is provided by moongoose but i could not figure it out from the documentation

Comment: if you want to see the implementation, try with the cast to string:

```User.findByIdAndDelete.toString()```

or even easly

```User.findByIdAndDelete + ""```